Using time-to-event as a covariate
Techniques to deal with right-censored survival endpoints are well established.
What if I'm interested in using the right-censored survival time as a covariate instead of a response?

What if? Probably nothing, except that using imperfectly estimated regressors brings about problems known as errors-in-variables. Other than that, is there something specific you have in mind?

If speaking about using event times to impute other variables there is a paper on this, referenced in this chapter.
